# Rails: dependent delete of models where association has non-standard name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, graph

I am modeling a directed graph in a Rails application (Rails 4.2). Among the model objects are `Vertex` and `Edge`.

A `vertex` can be part of many `edges` - hence we have the following relationship:

```
vertex -- has_many --> edges
```

An edge is defined between two vertices - an origin and a terminus. Thus, we define two associations of the edge with a vertex.

```
edge -- belongs_to --> :origin, class_name: 'Vertex'
edge -- belongs_to --> :terminus, class_name: 'Vertex'
```

I have also restricted the deletion of a vertex that is part of some edge. This ensures that I cannot delete a vertex which is part of the graph, unless it is a floating one.

But if I try to delete a floating vertex (one that is part of the graph but not part of any edge), I still get an error:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'edges.vertex_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  1 AS one FROM edges WHERE edges.vertex_id = ? LIMIT 1)`

Now the edges table obvious has no vertex_id, only an `origin_id` and a `terminus_id`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the changes suggested by Зелёный, the model looked like this:

```
class Vertex < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :edges, dependent: :restrict_with_error
end

class Edge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :origin, class_name 'Vertex', foreign_key: 'origin_id'
  belongs_to :terminus, class_name 'Vertex', foreign_key: 'terminus_id'
end
```

This still did not take care of deleting dependent records cleanly but had enough clues. I figured that there is obviously an ambiguity due to the `edges` member of `Vertex`. It's not clear in which of these edges is the current vertex playing the role of the origin, and in which ones is it the terminus?

A more natural model helped solve this. Instead of having a single `edges` references, I split it into two - `incoming_edges` and `outgoing_edges`, and specified the foreign keys for each.

```
class Vertex < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :incoming_edges, class_name: 'Edge', foreign_key: :terminus_id, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  has_many :outgoing_edges, class_name: 'Edge', foreign_key: :origin_id, dependent: :restrict_with_error
end
```

This helped fix the deletion issue.

Point to note: vertices cannot be deleted if they are part of one or more edges: hence the `restrict_with_error` clause. Bother vertices and edges are part of a `Graph` object. When `Graph` is deleted, it deletes the edges, and then the vertices which become disconnected after the edges are deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to specify [`foreign_key`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) option:

> Specify the foreign key used for the association. **By default this is
>   guessed to be the name of the association with an “_id” suffix**. So a
>   class that defines a belongs_to :person association will use
>   “person_id” as the default :foreign_key. Similarly, belongs_to
>   :favorite_person, class_name: "Person" will use a foreign key of
>   “favorite_person_id”.

```
belongs_to :origin, class_name: 'Vertex', foreign_key: 'origin_id'
belongs_to :terminus, class_name: 'Vertex', foreign_key: 'terminus_id'
```

Comment: Will this require a migration change as well?

Comment: Which changes it is require?